# Questions about Copy in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I have two ViewController Call "List" and "Detail".
The ListViewController have a data array, and when I click ListViewController's cell, ListViewController will push DetailViewController and pass data to the DetailViewController like this:

```
    let model = gMetaArray[indexPath.row]
    let vc = R.storyboard.main.comicDetailController()!
    vc.gMetaModel = model
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

So, in DetailViewController,I get the data and I use it:

```
    guard var data = gMetaModel else { return }
    data.sdatas.append(SDataModel())
```

When I modify the data, ListViewController's data array will change.

Why? When I pass data to DetailViewController, deep-copy does not happen? When I use `guard var data = gMetaModel else { return }`, deep-copy does not happen?

If not happen, how do I deep-copy the data?

Comment: This line you are passing a new object =`data.sdatas.append(SDataModel())`. I think your append is wrong.

Comment: I just want tell you, when I append data to `data.sdatas`, the ListViewController's data array will change.

Comment: When working with Swift data structures deep-copy/shallow-copy is not a good keyword. Just mind if the type is value-type or reference-type. There's no auto deep-copy magic in Swift. You may need to implement it by yourself. When using only value-types, you can expect nearly the same behavior as deep-copy, so it depends on your data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gMetaModel` is probably of a reference type. Variables like `gMetalModel` and `data` store a reference pointing to an object. In this case, the variable in Detail VC point to the same object as the variable in List VC. This is why changing the object via one variable will cause the changes to reflect when you access the object via the other variable.

To fix this, you can make the type of `gMetaModel` a value type, i.e. changing `class` to `struct`. This will make the object copy itself each time you assign it to another variable.

Alternatively, you can write a `createCopy` method yourself. Remember to also write `createCopy` methods for the reference types referenced by the type of `gMetaModel`, in order to make a deep copy.

A third alternative is to make the type of `gMetaModel` immutable. Make all the mutating methods create a new copy. This might not work so well in every case though.

Comment: so, when I use Class, it will always store a reference pointing to an object? `var` can not deep-copy? I had always thought that the `var` will create a separate object

Comment: @Eggplant Var will only create a separate object when you assign to it a value type.

Comment: So, I can not use deep-copy for a reference type, right? Well, I should find other function to prevent data change.

Comment: @Eggplant you can write a deep copy method yourself.